# Is it possible to remove "Nautilus search box" from the desktop?

Tags: nautilus

The Nautilus search box (I don't know if there is a name for it), it shows up whenever I start to type when I'm on the desktop (All applications are closed).

- Is it normal feature?
- Is it a problem or a bug?
- Is it possible to remove it from the desktop only?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a focus related problem. What are your focus stealing prevention settings in cssm?

Comment: @RolandTaylor , Focus Prevention level is set to **low**,   see http://i.imgur.com/qojQm.png .

Comment: @Binarylie: set it to normal and see if it still occurs.

Comment: I set it to normal and still the same.

Comment: @Binarylie: do you have any other applications open?

Comment: Currently, Just Chromium.

Comment: @Binarylie: if you have chromium selected, and start tying, and it opens the search box, then it's a bug.

Comment: @Roland Taylor No, maybe I didn't clarified what I wanted exactly at first.Sorry, My mistake! The thing is when I type and there are no open applications, just the desktop. I don't want this box to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think this is expected behavior when using the 'Have file manager handle the desktop' option. If it's showing up with that option disabled then that could be a bug.

I believe that option is now default enabled for both unity* & gnome-shell - I'm assuming you're using 11.10, you haven't specified what you're on.

Comment: Oh yes, 11.10. And yes I disable it using gnome-tweak. Thanks.

Comment: To turn this off with 14.04 use gnome-tweak: Desktop -> Icons on Desktop -> Off

Answer (score 0):

I just had this question answered for me in my related question. It is a Gnome Shell search the desktop tool. It highlights relevant things on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, Use The Tweak Tool and Turn Icons on Desktop off.
[image]