# Where does this floating text box come from?

Tags: input-devices, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to remove “Nautilus search box” from the desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73894/is-it-possible-to-remove-nautilus-search-box-from-the-desktop)

This is a bit strange, I would of filed it as a bug report, but I have no idea where it belongs.

Basically, if I focus a window like Empathy, or XChat (or any other GTK application which has a text input box) without selecting it's text input box, I get a little floating text input window which my keyboard focuses on (until I realize and manually select the correct box). I have no idea what's causing this, but it's becoming really, REALLY annoying.

[image]

How do I stop it?

Comment: Could you capture a screenshot of this event?

Comment: Sadly, I cant. I've tried the inbuilt screenshot button, and other screenshot applications, but as soon as the floating box looses focus, it disappears.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73894/is-it-possible-to-remove-nautilus-search-box-from-the-desktop  (answer is in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure If that's what You're talking about, but:

For example in nautilus such box is a normal feature. When You have no focus on any item and You begin to write letters such a box appears. It is for searching of items.
Try to write two first letters of some item You have in Your Empathy list. Like 'Jo'
and press enter. Then it should mark for example name John. If that's what happened it is a normal feature.