# When I'm on the desktop and I type anything a small window opens. What is it?

Tags: search, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the text box on the desktop for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100566/what-is-the-text-box-on-the-desktop-for)

When I'm on the desktop of Ubuntu, I type something and it appears in a small window in the lower right corner of the screen. What is that and how does it work?